# looking to use 2 enumerations to describe a class in java and assign them to the class in the main function

Tags: java, class, enums

I am trying to make a program to represent a deck of cards. I am using two enumerations to define a class Card. Then in main I am trying to assign suit and rank to a card.

```
public final class Card {
    enum Suit {
        HEARTS, SPADES, CLUBS, DIAMONDS
    }

    enum Rank {
        TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4),
        FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7),
        EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10),
        JACK(11), QUEEN(12), KING(13), ACE(14);

        private final int rank;

        private Rank(int rank) {
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        public int rank() {
            return this.rank;
        }
    }

    private Suit suit;
    private Rank rank;

    public void setRank(Rank rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setSuit(Suit suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }
}
```

And then in another file I get an error when I setRank and setSuit

```
import java.util.*;

public class deckOfCardsDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card jSpade = new Card();
        Card.setRank(JACK);
        Card.setSuit(SPADES);

        System.out.println( jSpade.getRank());
        System.out.println( jSpade.getSuit());
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: You can't call `setRank()` or `setSuit()` on the `Card` class, as it doesn't have any static methods.

Comment: What’s the error? A quick glance I’d guess that your main method doesn’t know what JACK or SPADES are as they aren’t defined in that method/class (you’d need Card.Rank.JACK etc)

Comment: I think you want `jSpade.setRank(JACK)` instead of `Card.setRank(JACK)`

Comment: ok I changed it to jSpade.setRank(JACK); and jSpade.setSuit(SPADES); 
but I'm still getting an error that says SPADES or JACK cannot be resolved to a variable am I defining them wrong ?

Comment: @Preston use Card.Rank.JACK

Comment: ok I figured it out thank you!
 jSpade.setRank(Card.Rank.JACK);
jSpade.setSuit(Card.Suit.SPADES);

Answer (score 1):

Three problems I can see:

No comma before FOUR, this is a simple syntax error:

```
enum Rank{TWO(2),THREE(3)FOUR(4),FIVE(5),
```

You call `set` methods on the class of `Card` which do not exist (they would need to be static and that would not make sense). You should call them on the instance:

```
Card.setRank(JACK);
Card.setSuit(SPADES);
```

This should be:

```
jSpade.setRank(JACK);
jSpade.setSuit(SPADES);
```

Thirdly, you need to qualify the enums with their classes (or import them statically):

```
jSpade.setRank(Card.Rank.JACK);
jSpade.setSuit(Card.Suit.SPADES);
```